# SSIS Script task suddenly keep unresponding and unable to open to view the code

Tags: ssis

I have been encountering a strange issue. Please refer to the snap added below.

I was able to run the package with 20 records in my flat file, but when I use 3 Million records, from then onwards the Script task keeps unresponsive and not able to edit.

Even not able to run previous packages, any one encountered the same problem, I am using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise edition. Can anyone suggest me what could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: It may depend on the code you are running, if it is very memory intensive or complex it could be using tons of CPU or memory and causes issues with VS.  If you restart VS (or even your PC) does the issue persist?

Comment: Thanks @Brad for your time to answer my question, it was because of some commands asking for user inputs, script component actually suppressed those notifications. I was able to find out when I debug the code inside the script component in a separate console application...Thanks a lot...